# Setup custom notification rules for all GitHub repos I am watching

Tags: github, github-api

GitHub recently added [a feature to control which out:](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-subscriptions-and-notifications-on-github/viewing-your-subscriptions#configuring-your-watch-settings-for-an-individual-repository)

- Pull requests
- Issues
- Releases
  should trigger notifications for watched repository.

This seems great as i never want to be notified about releases on most things I watch, since in most cases I am one of the core maintainers of what I am watching, and so I already know a release has happened -- probably I myself triggered a bot to make a release.

Is there a setting somewhere to configure the default setting for this?
I don't want to go an update all 200 repos by hand.
Perhaps there is an API endpoint i can poke?